# How to bulk remove and rename an array item exists in the mogo db document list from dotnetcore 2.0

Tags: mongodb, .net-core

I have mongo db document like below

```
{
    name : Class1,
    section
    {
      A1,
      A2,
      A3, 
    }
}
{
    name : Class2
    section
    {
      A1,
      A2,
      A3, 
      A4,
    }
}
{
    name : Class3
    section
    {
      A1,
      A2,
      A3, 
      A4,
    }
}
```

**I want remove A1 from all the class, To achive this I tried the below and its not working**

```
var entityCollection = _dbContext.GetCollection<TEntity>("class");
            var filter = Builders<TEntity>.Filter.Eq("section", "A1");
            var update = Builders<TEntity>.Update.Pull("section", "A1");
            var options = new UpdateOptions();
            await entityCollection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, options, cancellationToken);
```

**I want rename A4 into B1 for that I tried the below**

```
 var entityCollection = _dbContext.GetCollection<TEntity>("class");
        var filter = Builders<TEntity>.Filter.Eq("section", A4);
        var update = Builders<TEntity>.Update.Set("section", B1);
        var options = new UpdateOptions();
        await entityCollection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, options, cancellationToken);
```

Can any one help me to get out of this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are not valid MongoDB documents. Show the actual documents and not "pseudo-varaible" names. These are pretty basic things and if they are not working for you then now is not the time to be abstract. Also FYI you are asking "two" questions, where the format here is "one question at a time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue is resolved by changing the `TEntity`(mongo db  entity) to `BsonDocument` in the code and for rename I have done the below change**

```
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.AddToSet("section", B1);
var options = new UpdateOptions();
collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, options, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
var update2 = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pull("section", A4);
collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update2, options, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```